error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngSrc' since it isn't a known property of 'img'
I tried to use NgOptimizedImage directive. I'm using Angular 18.
My problem is the image do not displayed, always got the following error
X [ERROR] NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngSrc' since it isn't a known property of 'img'. [plugin angular-compiler]

In the parent modue I imported the NgOptimizedImage.
Here is my code:
<div class="awards-content">
        <div class="awards-screen">
            <div  class="align-awards text-primary">
                <h4 class="label-title">Awards...</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                <span class="text-primary">
                    <a class="spacer"
                      href="https://github.com/lkovari/LKovariHome/blob/master/src/app/layout-pages/awards/awards.component.ts">
                      <img [src]="githubLogoPath" width="16" height="16" alt="githubLogoPath">
                    </a>Technical notes:</span> under CONSTRUCTION, will use ngOptimizedImage directive</p>
            </div>
            <div class="image-content">
                <ul>
                    @for (imageDescriptor of imageDescriptors; track imageDescriptor.id) {
                        <li class="text-primary">  {{ imageDescriptor.alt }}
                            <img
                                class="img-responsive"
                                [ngSrc]="imageDescriptor.fileName" 
                                [width]="imageDescriptor.width"
                                [height]="imageDescriptor.height"
                                [alt]="imageDescriptor.alt"
                                ngSrcset="200w, 400w, 600w, 800w, 1000w, 1200w, 1600w, 2000w, 3000w">
                        </li>            
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>            
        </div>
</div>

ts:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ImageDescriptor } from './models/image-descriptor.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-awards',
  templateUrl: './awards.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./awards.component.scss']
})
export class AwardsComponent implements OnInit {
  githubLogoPath: string;
  public years: number;
  imageDescriptors: ImageDescriptor[] = [
    { id : 1, fileName: 'assets/images/2022Q2LeaderboardWinnerGT50.png', width: 434, height: 640, alt: 'Leaderboard winner Q2 of 2022' },
    { id : 2, fileName: 'assets/images/2021Q4CaughtAtYourBest.png', width: 791, height: 916, alt: 'Caught at your best Q4 2021' },
    { id : 3, fileName: 'assets/images/2018CertificateOfRecognition20years.png', width: 800, height: 583, alt: '20 years of service' },
    { id : 4, fileName: 'assets/images/2016Q4CaughtAtYourBest.png', width: 1280, height: 983, alt: 'Caught at your best Q4 2016' },
    { id : 5, fileName: 'assets/images/2015Q4CaughtAtYourBest.png', width: 1280, height: 913, alt: 'Caught at your best Q4 2015' },
    { id : 6, fileName: 'assets/images/icagile-cert2014.png', width: 800, height: 583, alt: 'IcAgile course Certificate' },
    { id : 7, fileName: 'assets/images/AmkaiStockOptions1050A.png', width: 1199, height: 913, alt: 'Stock Option Series A' }
  ]

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const date = new Date();
    this.years = date.getFullYear();
    this.githubLogoPath = 'assets/logos/GitHub-Mark-32px.png';
  }

}

If somebody has any idea I will appreciate it.

Can you provide the code for the mentioned parrent module in the question?

I figured out what was the problem. I used non standalone component. So with standalone component it works well.

I figured out what was the problem.
I turn my component to standalone.

Go to the module, where you have added AwardsComponent to the declarations array. Ensure you have imported NgOptimizedImage in the imports array of the same module where it is declared, this will get rid of the error!
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ...
  AwardsComponent,
  ...
  ],
  imports: [
  ...
  NgOptimizedImage,
  ...
  ],
})
export class SomeModule {}


Murali,
That was the first step, what I did. import the NgOptimizedImage in the parent module.
In-spite of the fact that when I use [ngSrc]= I got the error, if I use ngSrc= no error but no image displayed at all. The image paths are correct also.

@L.Kvri then please share a stackblitz with the issue happens or GitHub repo, you have not even shared the parent module, how to check the issue?

I figured out what was the problem. I used non standalone component. So with standalone component it works well.
